# View that Shows Result Links

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that prints the titles of my 10 most recent news item content.  I also want to print the URL to these news items.   How do I do this?  When I edit the view, under Fields, I see a Link field, but the problem is that it prints the word "view" instead of http://mysites.com/my-first-news-item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I almost got it....the field i'm looking for is called `Content:Path`.  Right now, it prints /my-first-news-item.  All I need to do now is have it print the domain name as well.....almost there.

**EDIT**
Figured out the last part.  To print out the absolute path, make sure the field also has the setting `Use absolute link (begins with "http://")` checked